# open mp three for loops with reduction

Tags: c++, openmp

i need to multiply two 10x10 matrices using open mp. I decided to split the rows of one matrice into groups of 3rows,3 rows and 4 rows. how do i fix this code for the first three rows ?

```
#pragma omg parallel for reduction(+:m[p][q])
        {
            for (p = 0; p < 3; p++)
                for (q = 0; q < 10; q++)
                    for (k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
                    {
                        m[p][q] += l[p][k] * o[k][q];
                    }
        }
```

Comment: Your approach is wrong from the start -- write your code such that OpenMP takes care of the decomposition of work onto threads.  A good approach would be to first write your serial code then simply wrap the outermost loop with an OpenMP `parallel for` pragma and take it from there.

Comment: 10x10 matrices are tiny. Don't waste your time with OpenMP.

Answer (score 2):

For a start - don't split the matrix yourself, but let OpenMP take care of sharing the work in the loops, e.g.

```
#pragma omg parallel for
{
    for (p = 0; p < 10; p++)
        for (q = 0; q < 10; q++)
            for (k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
            {
                m[p][q] += l[p][k] * o[k][q];
            }
}
```

In this code there is no need for a `reduction` because all concurrent write operations happen to different elements of `m`. Even if you `collapse(2)` the first two loops, you are still fine in that regard.

That said, optimizing matrix multiplication is an immensely complex topic on modern hardware. Parallelizing it even more so. If you want to get performance, use a [BLAS implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms#Implementations) that is optimized for your architecture. If you want to learn - I suggest you start with the serial implementation and then go on parallelizing it. There plenty of educational material available for either.

Comment: You do have a reduction in the inner loop, which might be optimized better with a local sum variable:

Comment: With such short loops, OpenMP will slow it down significantly.

Comment: @tim18, I'm not going down the rabbit hole of performance of parallel matrix multiplication in an answer on SO - I focus on correctness / validity. Practically you use a BLAS library and if you want to get close to that on your own, you write a master thesis.

Comment: @tim18, you're much better off swapping the order of the q and k loops. Look at `m[p][q] += l[p][k] * o[k][q];` If your innermost loop goes over q it's obviously much better usage of the cache. So using a local sum variables is a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, in case the loop lengths become large enough to benefit from simd, swapping those loops assures stride 1 so should auto-vectorize easily.  Depending on the compiler and command line options (or even on the use of __restrict), the swap might be done automatically. Not swapping and using a scalar reduction variable may work better by reducing memory traffic, but it may need more aggressive optimization.